# Input isn't recognized as belonging to a list

Tags: python

I made this simple code that let's the user see if their input is in the fibonacci sequence or not. However the code always returns "This number is not fibonacci" even if I input a number that is in fact fibonacci. I tried printing the list and it does include the first 100 fibonacci numbers as it should. What's the problem folks?

```
number = 1
x = 0
while x < 100:
    number = number + fibonacci[-2]
    fibonacci.append(number)
    x=x+1


guess = input("Number that you think is fibonacci: ")

if guess in fibonacci:
    print("This number is fibonacci")
else:
    print("This number is not fibonacci")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you store integers in the fibonacci list, you will also need to take integers as input. `input()` takes in a string as default, so you have to convert it.

```
guess = int(input("Number that you think is fibonacci: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are checking if a string is in a list of integers, to fix this problem cast the input to an int using the `int()` function.

```
number = 1
x = 0
while x < 100:
    number = number + fibonacci[-2]
    fibonacci.append(number)
    x=x+1


guess = int(input("Number that you think is fibonacci: "))

if guess in fibonacci:
    print("This number is fibonacci")
else:
    print("This number is not fibonacci")
```